# Update Object in all other Struct Swift

Tags: swift, object, swiftui

I'm trying to learn Swift.

I have 2 structs

```
struct Player : Identifiable {
var id = UUID()
let teamId : UUID
let namePlayer : String
}

struct Team : Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    let nameTeam : String
}
```

In my views, I have a TabView

```
struct GeneralView: View {
let player : Player
let team : Team
@State private var selectedTab: Int = 2

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {

            Settings(player: player, team : team)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "gearshape.fill")
                    Text("Settings")
                }.tag(1)
            
            TeamGeneralView(player: player, team : team)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "person.3.fill")
                    Text("Team")
                }.tag(2)
```

Let's try with namePlayer : "Me" nameTeam : "Blue".
When I am in my TabView Settings, How can I update team.nameTeam to "Red" and see it in TeamGeneralView ?

That's a little "obscure" for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to make `player` and `team` into `@State` variables in `GeneralView`, and pass a `Binding` to the `Settings` view:

```
struct GeneralView: View {
   @State var player: Player
   @State var team: Team
   // ...

   var body: someView {
       // ...
       Settings(player: $player, team: $team)

       // ...
       TeamGeneralView(player: player, team : team)
   }
}
```

Then, `Settings` would declare its properties as `@Binding`. It would be something like this:

```
struct Settings: View {
   @Binding var player: Player
   @Binding var team: Team
 
   var body: some View {
      VStack() {
         TextField("player", text: $player.namePlayer)
         TextField("team", text: $team.nameTeam)
      }
   }
}
```